# ASP.NET Message Handler return json if custom header found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible the following scenario:

Create a message handler that will check every incoming request. If the request contains a custom header key: "My-Header" and it's value is: "True" then stop the request and return a custom json to client otherwise, if the header is not present or if the header is present but the value is "False" then allow the request to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would something along the lines of the code shown below. This is assuming the JSON you want to send back would be represented by `ErrorModel` here. To add the handler to the ASP.NET Web API handler pipeline, look at [this good article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) on how it is wired up.

```
public class MyHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string headerTokenValue;
        const string customHeaderKey = "My-Header";

        if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues(
                customHeaderKey,
                out headerTokenValue)
            || headerTokenValue.ToLower() != "true")
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(
                        HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        new ErrorModel
                        {
                            Description = "error stuff",
                            Status = "Ooops"
                        });
                    response.Content = new StringContent(json);
                    // Ensure return type is JSON:
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                       new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                    return response;    
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now. However Stephen Cleary mentioned in one of my posts, using Task in server side code is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess maybe this is better ?

```
............

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new ErrorModel
                    {
                        Description = "error stuff",
                        Status = "Ooops"
                    });
response.Content = new StringContent(json);

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
tcs.SetResult(response);
return tcs.Task;
```